# How to build a causal model with multiple treatment and multiple outcomes using EconML library in Python?

Tags: python, causality

I have been looking to see if DoWhy supports  Multiple Treatments (T) and Multiple Outcomes (Y) causal framework and it seems to be the case. For example, `CausalForest` may be a good candidate using EconMl as the Py libary.

My question is how would I define and pass parameters for both the Treatment and the Outcome when setting up the model? Would the below code work to get the expected output I added at the end?

```
model = CausalModel(data=df,
                    treatment=["T1", "T2", "T3"],
                    outcome=["Y1", "Y2"])
```

Again, I want to ensure that my treatments (T1-T3) can be all continuous variables between 0 - 10 for example. I am looking for an output like this with combinatorics of treatment on the outcome variables:

```
user_id | T1 | T2 | T3   | CATE Y1  | CATE Y2
1       | 4  | 0  | 0    | 0.2      | 0.1
1       | 1  | 6  | 1    | 0.22     | 0.13
1       | 2  | 1  | 8    | 0.62     | -0.2
...
```

Any help is very appreciated.